# Crop Image from camera before upload (Phonegap)

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, crop

i would like to ask you..

i have a code... using phonegap.. but i was confused about how to call / crop the image after take it from camera / file manager...

here the code...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var deviceReady = false;

    /**
     * Take picture with camera
     */
    function takePicture() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(
            function(uri) {
                var img = document.getElementById('camera_image');
                img.style.visibility = "visible";
                img.style.display = "block";
                img.src = uri;
                window.location.hash = "#page2";
                /*document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Success"; */


            },
            function(e) {
                console.log("Error getting picture: " + e);
                document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Error getting picture.";
            },
            { quality: 50, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, targetWidth: 1153, targetHeight: 385
            }

            );
    };

    /**
     * Select picture from library
     */
    function selectPicture() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(
            function(uri) {
                var img = document.getElementById('camera_image');
                img.style.visibility = "visible";
                img.style.display = "block";
                img.src = uri;
                document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Success";
                window.location.hash = "#page2";
            },
            function(e) {
                console.log("Error getting picture: " + e);
                document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Error getting picture.";
            },
            { quality: 50, targetWidth: 1153, targetHeight: 385, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY});
    };

    /**
     * Upload current picture
     */
    function uploadPicture() {

        // Get URI of picture to upload
        var img = document.getElementById('camera_image');
        var imageURI = img.src;
        if (!imageURI || (img.style.display == "none")) {
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Take picture or select picture from library first.";
            return;
        }

        // Verify server has been entered
        server = document.getElementById('serverUrl').value;
        if (server) {

            // Specify transfer options
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="file";
            options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
            options.chunkedMode = false;

            // Transfer picture to server
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
            ft.upload(imageURI, server, function(r) {
                document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Upload successful: "+r.bytesSent+" bytes uploaded.";
                viewUploadedPictures();
                $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                window.location.hash = "#page3";
            }, function(error) {
                $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Upload failed: Code = "+error.code;               
            }, options);
        }
    }

    /**
     * View pictures uploaded to the server
     */
    function viewUploadedPictures() {

        // Get server URL
        server = document.getElementById('serverUrl').value;
        if (server) {

            // Get HTML that lists all pictures on server using XHR 
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            // Callback function when XMLHttpRequest is ready
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4){

                    // HTML is returned, which has pictures to display
                    if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                        document.getElementById('server_images').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }

                    // If error
                    else {
                        document.getElementById('server_images').innerHTML = "Error retrieving pictures from server.";
                    }
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", server , true);
            xmlhttp.send();         
        }   
    }

    /**
     * Function called when page has finished loading.
     */
    function init() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {deviceReady = true;}, false);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            if (!deviceReady) {
                alert("Error: PhoneGap did not initialize.  Demo will not run correctly.");
            }
        },2000);
    }

    </script>

  </head>
  <body onload="init();">
  <!-- Page 1 -->
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
   <!-- Page 1 Header -->
   <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Ambil Gambar</h1>
   </div>
   <!-- Page 1 Content -->
   <div data-role="content">
      <center>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="takePicture();">
    <img src="image/camera.png" width="150px" height="150px">
    </a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <b>Atau</b>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="selectPicture();">
    <img src="image/upload.png">
    </a>

    </center>

   </div>
   <!-- Page 1 Footer -->
   <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>Footer 1</h4>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- Page 2 -->
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
   <!-- Page 2 Header -->
   <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Header 2</h1>
   </div>
   <!-- Page 2 Content -->
   <div data-role="content">

       <img style="width:100%;visibility:hidden;display:none;" id="camera_image" src="" />
      <input type="button" onclick="uploadPicture();" value="Upload Picture" />
      <input id="serverUrl" type="text" value="http://kiosban.com/android/camera/upload.php" />
      Status : <span id="camera_status"></span>
      <a href="#page3">Skip</a>
   </div>
   <!-- Page 2 Footer -->
   <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>Footer 2</h4>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- Page 3 -->
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
   <!-- Page 3 Header -->
   <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Header 3</h1>
   </div>
   <!-- Page 3 Content -->
   <div data-role="content">
   <div id="server_images"></div>
      <h3>Server:</h3>
        <b>Images on server:</b>
        <div id="server_images"></div>

        <input type="button" onclick="viewUploadedPictures();" value="View Uploaded Pictures" />
   </div>
   <!-- Page 2 Footer -->
   <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>Footer 2</h4>
   </div>
</div>



  </body>
</html>
```

I want to call image crop on #page2, so there is an upload button to upload the cropped image...

can anybody help me do that??

Comment: Ah yes, and _work on your accept_ rate, if I saw it before I am not sure I'd answer.

Answer (score 7):

PhoneGap does not have built-in crop features. Some platforms (iPhone for sure) allows the *user* to crop the picture after taking it with the camera but *before* it would be returned to your JavaScript code if you pass the allowEdit = true parameter to getPicture. But you won't have control here from your script.

You'll have to implement the cropping feature yourself from JavaScript. It is easier then expected with the canvas tag of HTML5. You can find a pretty tutorial [here](http://www.digitalnoiz.com/cocoa/capture-image-video-and-crop/).

Comment: It is very possible that the code posted in the original tutorial is outdated. Unfortunately I didn't work with Phonegap since the last two years so I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: Okay Thanks... Can you share your experience with phonegap? how was it? Actually I am new in this?

Comment: With pg more or less you can get a working app (assuming that it has API for everything you need) but my the user experience will be always a kind of bulky: you won't ever get so fluid animations, view transitions, etc like if you had done the same thing with native APIs. I would not ship any code in production written in pg but there are plenty of them out in the app stores. On the other hand for prototyping it might be an excellent decision.

Comment: Means as your perspective native apps are more better than pg apps.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for this(it is too late but used for someone like me) but after taking image you need to pass the image path to the plugin(Native android) for croping.

put the following code in your image capture or pick image from gallery(in your index.html):

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI){
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, function(fileEntry){
            fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) { 
                  var imagedata ="sample/new001.img";
                  // able to get the image location using phonegap
                cropImage.createEvent(imagedata);

            }); 

     }, fail);
  }, fail, { quality: 50, 
         destinationType: destinationType.NATIVE_URI,
        sourceType: pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY 
});
```

after that **crop.image.js** should be like (include this **file name** in your index.html)

```
var cropImage =  {
    createEvent: function(fileName) {
        cordova.exec(
                null, // success callback function
                null, // error callback function
            'CropImage', // mapped to our native Java class called "CropImage"
            'GetImageName', // with this action name
            [fileName]
        );
    }
}
```

Your java code is like

```
public class CropImage extends CordovaPlugin{
public final String ACTION_GET_IMAGE_NAME = "GetImageName";
Uri myUri;
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
   // Log.e(TAG,"Inside Version plugin.");
    boolean result = false;
    if(action.equals(ACTION_GET_IMAGE_NAME)) {
        try {
            myUri = Uri.parse(args.getString(0));
            cropCapturedImage(myUri);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        result = true;
    }


    return result;
}

public void cropCapturedImage(Uri picUri){
    //call the standard crop action intent 
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    //indicate image type and Uri of image
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
    //set crop properties
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
    // for save the image in same location with same name.
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"your image location here");
    cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));            
    cropIntent.putExtra("output", Uri.fromFile(f)); 
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", false);

    //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
    this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this,cropIntent, 2);
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    //Log.e("final", String.valueOf(requestCode));
    /*if(requestCode == 2){
        //Create an instance of bundle and get the returned data
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        //get the cropped bitmap from extras
        Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
    }*/
}

}
```

Don't forget to add this class in your CONFIG.XML and add the necessary permissions. Feel free to ask any doubts.