# How to crop an image using Cordova in android

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

Trying to crop an image using cordova after capturing image..
unable to crop image. I am using external library to crop image.
Library link : [Library link](https://github.com/raananw/PhoneGap-Image-Resizer/blob/master/README.md)
please check below code.

```
 function onPhotoDataSuccess (imageData) {
window.imageResizer.resizeImage(
                  function(data) { 
                var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
                    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data.imageData;

                  }, function (error) {
                    console.log("Error : \r\n" + error);
                  }, imageDataInBase64, 0.5, 0.5, {resizeType:ImageResizer.RESIZE_TYPE_FACTOR ,format:'jpg'});
    }
```

LogCat :

```
10-17 12:18:28.391: D/CordovaActivity(22365): CB-3064: The errorUrl is null
10-17 12:18:28.391: W/CursorWrapperInner(22365): Cursor finalized without prior close()
10-17 12:18:28.431: D/CordovaLog(22365): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1044 :     processMessage failed: Error: ReferenceError: imageDataInBase64 is not defined
10-17 12:18:28.431: I/chromium(22365): [INFO:CONSOLE(1044)] "processMessage failed: Error: ReferenceError: imageDataInBase64 is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1044)
10-17 12:18:28.431: D/CordovaLog(22365): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1045 : processMessage failed: Stack: ReferenceError: imageDataInBase64 is not defined
10-17 12:18:28.431: D/CordovaLog(22365):     at onPhotoDataSuccess (file:///android_asset/www/app/controller/MainController.js?_dc=1413527241291:112:20)
10-17 12:18:28.431: D/CordovaLog(22365):     at Object.cordova.callbackFromNative (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:292:54)
10-17 12:18:28.431: D/CordovaLog(22365):     at processMessage (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1039:21)
10-17 12:18:28.431: D/CordovaLog(22365):     at Function.androidExec.processMessages (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1076:13)
10-17 12:18:28.431: D/CordovaLog(22365):     at pollOnce (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:944:17)
10-17 12:18:28.431: D/CordovaLog(22365):     at pollOnceFromOnlineEvent (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:939:5)
```

Comment: check your url path,if it is correct or not.Also it is saying that imageDataInBase64 is not defined, so check that also and debug base64 part.

Comment: i wrote a plugin for crop image in phonegap using android refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151995/crop-image-from-camera-before-upload-phonegap/25368730#25368730